# Openpyxl Formula filling unique row values for entire column

Tags: python, excel, formula, openpyxl

I'm trying to write a formula into a cell and write for the entire column. However, for each cell in the column, it reads `=(E2-F2)/C2`. For each cell on the same column how do I get it so reads `(E3-F3)/C3` and so on?

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('yes.xlsx')
Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

n = '=(E2-F2)/C2'
for cellObj in list(Sheet.columns)[6]:
    cellObj.value = n
wb.save("row_creation_loop.xlsx")
```

Comment: For me, you're goal is not clearly stated. You say it reads a formula (gotten from the formula specified in your code), but you want it to read a different formula. Just changing the hard-coded formula in your code won't fix it? Are you instead wanting to increment values in the formula for each row down the column? If so incrementing a row variable in a loop and casting it to a string would work, but more clarification on what your goal is would help offer a solution.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I'm trying to have incremented values in the formula down each row of the same column.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. You probably could use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the for-loop to get the row number, and then assign that row value to `n`. Maybe something like: `for row, cellObj in enumerate(list(Sheet.columns)[6]):` ... `n = '=(E%d-F%d)/C%d' % (row, row, row)`

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 3):

From my comment, here is the `for`-loop code in full:

```
# n = '=(E2-F2)/C2' # move this assignment into the for-loop

for row, cellObj in enumerate(list(Sheet.columns)[6]):
    print cellObj
    n = '=(E%d-F%d)/C%d' % (row, row, row)
    # print n # check that n gets assigned correct string value
    cellObj.value = n
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add +1 at the `r(row, row, row)`.

```
# n = '=(E2-F2)/C2' # move this assignment into the for-loop

for row, cellObj in enumerate(list(Sheet.columns)[6]):
    print cellObj
    n = '=(E%d-F%d)/C%d' % (row, row, row)
    # print n # check that n gets assigned correct string
```