# Openpyxl fill formula in Excel column

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am working in Python 3.6.2 and openpyxl and I have a formula in an Excel column that I need to fill in for the entire column of data.

The formula is :

=TEXT(G2, "00") so I want G2 to increment to G3, G4 and so on down the column.

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Workbook.xlsx")
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Data')


n = '=TEXT(G2, "00")'
for row, cellObj in enumerate(list(ws.columns)[10]):
    print (cellObj)
    n = '=TEXT(G%d, "00")' % (row, row, row)

    cellObj.value = n
wb.save('Workbook.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

I am getting an error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'

Thank you in advance for any help that you can provide.

**Edit 1:**

It is really a duplicate of this question

[Openpyxl Formula filling for entire column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948778/openpyxl-formula-filling-for-entire-column)

However I cannot get the example there to work either. I am getting a very annoying syntax error.

Comment: The code can't be complete because `ws` should be a `Worksheet` instance but is obviously a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iteration over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iteration-over-worksheets-rows-columns)

Comment: I receive an error 'invalid syntax' on the wb.save('Workbook.xlsx') line. The line is not indented as it is the first line of code after the for loop. It is my understanding that python will close loops upon seeing a line of code that is not indented (after lines that are indented).